# Pact JS Provider: how to run consumer tests used in PACT workshop when returning 'Unrecognized CLI Parameter'

Tags: javascript, testing, npm, jestjs, pact

The tests were working on my Windows desktop, but they keep failing on this macbook. I cloned this [repository](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-workshop-js) and when I try to run the tests I receive this error:

```
$ npm run test:pact --prefix consumer

> consumer@0.1.0 pretest:pact
> rimraf pacts/*.json


> consumer@0.1.0 test:pact
> CI=true react-scripts test --testTimeout=30000 pact.spec.js

● Unrecognized CLI Parameter:

  Unrecognized option "testTimeout".

  CLI Options Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html
```

The package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "consumer",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router": "^6.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "spectre.css": "^0.5.8",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@pact-foundation/pact": "^10.0.0-beta.62",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "nock": "^11.7.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "CI=true react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "pretest:pact": "rimraf pacts/*.json",
    "test:pact": "CI=true react-scripts test --testTimeout=30000 pact.spec.js"    
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

If I try to run the consumer tests locally, I got this:

```
$ npm run test

> consumer@0.1.0 test
> CI=true react-scripts test

PASS src/api.spec.js
FAIL src/api.pact.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enabled')

      1 | import path from "path";
    > 2 | import {
        | ^
      3 |   PactV3,
      4 |   MatchersV3,
      5 |   SpecificationVersion,

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/pino-pretty/index.js:28:30)
      at getPrettyStream (node_modules/pino/lib/tools.js:183:27)
      at normalizeArgs (node_modules/pino/lib/tools.js:352:16)
      at pino (node_modules/pino/pino.js:78:28)
      at Object.createLogger (node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-core/src/logger/pino.ts:5:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-core/src/logger/index.ts:10:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-core/src/service.ts:4:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-core/src/server.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-core/src/pact.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-core/src/index.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@pact-foundation/src/httpPact/index.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@pact-foundation/src/index.ts:25:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/api.pact.spec.js:2:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.274s
Ran all test suites.
```

It does not run the pact tests from the consumer side.

Already tried a lot of different things, removing 'CI=true' in the `package.json`, removing the timeout, nothing seems to work it out. Although, the tests on the provider side are running correcly

Comment: Best to raise an issue on the repository with instructions to reproduce (e.g. `git clone ...`, then `npm i` then check out step x etc.). It sounds like perhaps the npm packages weren't installed correctly or perhaps there is a global version of jest/react-scripts that is out of date.

Comment: you got that right, I didn't notice that `npm install` was having some errors